# How to number all the lines in a text that do not have characters "b" and "c" in them?

Tags: bash

I want to number all the lines that do not contain a character "b" or "c" in the line. How to do that?

My first idea was to write this:

```
ls -l | nl -bp'[!bc]'
```

because without an exclamation mark it numbers only the lines that do contain characters "b" or "c". I thought that exclamation mark would inverse this numbering, but it did not..

I would need somehow to inverse it so that it would number lines that do not contain these characters. Could you write this command using nl -bp?

Comment: @WojtekT The output is wrong. It's "do not" vs. "do".

Comment: @JohnKugelmansupportsMonica oops i read it 5 times incorrectly :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number lines that consist entirely of allowed characters.

```
ls -l | nl -bp'^[^bc]*$'
```

- `[^bc]` matches any character that is neither `b` nor `c`. If it were `[bc]` then it'd match only `b`s and `c`s. `^` [negates a character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), so `[^bc]` matches anything that's *not* a `b` or `c`.
- The `^` at front and `$` are [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). They require the entire line to match, not just a part of the line.

  Note that this use of `^` is entirely unrelated to the `^` inside square brackets. It's an unfortunate reuse of the same symbol. One is an anchor and the other is a character class negation.
- `*` matches [zero or more](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of the preceding item. You may have seen `.*` before, which matches anything at all because a [dot](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) matches any single character. The use here is similar, except instead of `.` we have `[^bc]`.

Comment: Could you please explain for me what is the logic behind '^[^bc]*$'    ? Especially I do not understand why there has to be two these characters "^" . The character * mean any following symbol right? And $ mean en end of a line?

Comment: Do the added bullets help? I'm so used to regexes I can't tell if my writeup is clear or cryptic.

Comment: Thank you! Actually only one thing is not clear to me. Why doesn't it work than to write for example: `ls -l | nl -bp'^[bc]*$'` to number all the lines that contain characters "b" and "c"? I thought that it should work since we just exclude the negation..

Comment: That would number lines that contain *only* `b`s and `c`s.

Comment: I thought that as well but it did not number any line when I have tried it..

Comment: Only option `ls -l | nl -bp'[bc]'` works for that case for me..

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` expression:

```
ls -l | awk '/^[^bc]*$/{ $0 = ++c FS $0 }1'
```

or the same with *negated* regex pattern:

```
ls -l | awk '!/[bc]/{ $0 = ++c FS $0 }1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use **ls** I think you want to print all the files in a folder.
You could use: ls -l | grep -v "[bc]".

Comment: I want to number lines that occur after printing the long list of files and folders. But not all the lines, but only number those lines that do not contain a character "b" or "c" in them..

Comment: Then you can use:
ls -l | grep -v "[bc]" | grep -n